# Controller returns json as a string

Tags: go, beego

I load a list of items from the database and would like to return it as Json.
it works well but the response is not a json object, its a string with is a problem on the receiver side.

```
var products []*database.Product
num, err := o.QueryTable("product").Filter("date", date).All(&products)
fmt.Printf("Returned Rows Num: %d, %s", num, err)

var jsonData []byte
jsonData, err2 := json.Marshal(products)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

this.Data["json"] = string(jsonData)
this.ServeJSON()
```

it returns

```
"[{\"Id\":\"68e7512f-ea50-45d3-a89e-845c7621b33d\",\"Producttypeid\":\"62c9ff0a-f599-4ac1-9442-ebae3bc049c1\",\"Producti...
```

but should be

```
[{"Id":"68e7512f-ea50-45d3-a89e-845c7621b33d","Producttypeid":"62c9ff0a-f599-4ac1-9442-ebae3bc049c1","Producti...
```

adding annotations like `json:"id"` does not change anything.
is it a problem because it is an array?
do I have to wrap that inside a struct?

Comment: Well you're setting `this.Data["json"]` to string value of marshalled products. Try to do just `this.Data["json"] = products`

Comment: this is one of this moments you want to bite your own ass... thanks! it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments from Kosanovic the solution is very simple, just dont marshal yourself.

```
var products []*database.Product
num, err := o.QueryTable("product").Filter("date", date).All(&products)
fmt.Printf("Returned Rows Num: %d, %s", num, err)

this.Data["json"] = products
this.ServeJSON()
```